# select column of JSON arrays and show elements as new columns

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I have a Postgres DB with a column that has a JSON array for the value in each row.

Example:

```
id | json_data
1  | [{"sub_id":"a1", "flag":"true", "type":"something"}, {"sub_id":"a2", "flag":"true", "type":"something"}]
2  | [{"sub_id":"b1", "flag":"false", "type":"something"}, {"sub_id":"b2", "flag":"false", "type":"something"}]
3  | [{"sub_id":"c1", "flag":"true", "type":"something"}]
```

I want to be able create a new view so that I can interact with data structured like this:

```
id | sub_id | flag  | type
1  | a1     | true  | something
1  | a2     | true  | something
2  | b1     | false | something
2  | b2     | false | something
3  | c1     | true  | something
```

Perhaps there is something I am not understanding from the Postgres documentation. It seems like I need to to leverage `json_array_elements` but all of the documentation and related examples I see show the JSON being passed as a string to this function.

How to I do I use this for each row of a given column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unnest using `jsonb_array_elements`, then you can access each key:

```
select t.id, 
       j.e ->> 'sub_id' as sub_id,
       j.e ->> 'flag' as flag,
       j.e ->> 'type' as type
from the_table t
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(t.json_data::jsonb) as j(e)
order by t.id;
```

This assumes your column is defined as `jsonb` (which it should be). If it's just `json` you need to use `json_array_elements()`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am struggling a bit to understand the convention used here where we have "t", "j", "e" and "the_table" defined. 

I assume t = the name of the table I am querying. What value is expected for "j"? 

Is "the_table" simply a "virtual" table that is being created ad-hoc so that it can be included in the cross join?

Sorry for these simplistic questions--and thanks again for taking the time to have a look.

Comment: @MattJackson  Those are [table aliases](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES)

Comment: Using this:

```
select alias.id, 
       j.e ->> 'sub_id' as sub_id
from myTable AS alias
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(alias.json_data) as j(e)
order by alias.id;
```

I see this error: 

ERROR:  function jsonb_array_elements(text) does not exist
LINE 4:   cross join jsonb_array_elements(alias.json_data) as j(e)

Any ideas?

Comment: @MattJackson: then your column isn't a `jsonb` (or `json`) column, but it's defined as `text`  - you will need to cast it. See my edit

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name ! Really appreciated!